# Update action package with gactions always returns request timeout

Tags: actions-on-google

I created a project under actions console and made a test action package for smart home app. I want to try uploading the action package I have using gactions. However, every time I execute this command

```
./gactions --verbose  update --action_package action.json --project my_project_id
```

the result is always like this:

```
Unable to update: Patch https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/agents/my_project_id?updateMask=agent.draftActionPackage.actions%2Cagent.draftActionPackage.conversations&validateOnly=false: Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: dial tcp 216.58.200.45:443: i/o timeout
```

I checked the verbose log and I noticed that it is reading some data from creds.data

```
Reading credentials from: creds.data
```

Then I noticed the contents in creds.data contains the access token and the expiry time. But the expiry time is july 18, which is a lot of days from now. I am not sure if this is the case that causes timeout error. And I also don't know how to update the creds.data to get a new access token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright. I noticed that a part of this error is my net problem. But I was able to open yahoo and other sites, while the update just didn't work. But nevermind, I just switched to a different Wi-Fi.

Then I deleted the creds.data. And executed the update command again, this will come out.

```
Gactions needs access to your Google account. Please copy & paste the URL below into a web browser and follow the instructions there. Then copy and paste the authorization code from the browser back here.
Visit this URL: 
 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=237807841406-o6vu1tjkq8oqjub8jilj6vuc396e2d0c.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fassistant+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Factions.builder&state=state 
Enter authorization code:
```

Then I followed the instructions above, got the authorization code, copied and pasted it in the console, and everything works fine now.

Comment: Hi I have tried same, but am getting Access blocked: Assistant CLI’s request is invalid message